# Entity abstract attributes were copied to extended entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a very strange error:

```
Fatal error: Access level to Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Book::$title
must be public (as in class Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\AbstractBook) in   
/var/www/html/src/Acme/DemoBundle/Entity/Book.php on line 614 Call 
Stack: 0.0002 674960 1
```

The line 614 is not available and the craziest thing is, the error is away when I upload my whole entity folder from my ide to my local ubunutu image manually.

This is my AbstractBookEntity:

```
 namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Entity;

 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
 use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

 /** 
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass 
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class AbstractBook
{



/**
 * @var string $title
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
 */
public $title;
```

The Book class:

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Book
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="book")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\DemoBundle\Repository\BookRepository")       
 */
class Book extends AbstractBook {
```

**UPDATE:**

I detected that attributes from the abstract Entity where copied and declared as private into the extendes Entity but how does it happen?

Comment: What's the complete code of the `Book` class?

Comment: This could be a cache error. Have you cleared the cache?

Comment: @Ocramius: here is my book class: http://jsfiddle.net/S7F7g/ there are a lot of other attributes, but the intsanciation is always the same and have noe connection to this error i think.

Comment: @Patt  I cleared the cache so many times

Comment: Did you try to reproduce this in an insulated environment? Do you have `apc.stat = 0` by chance?

Comment: yes, i have it on every environment. what is apc.stat = 0?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to clear your cache: `php app/console cache:clear` or if this fails: `rm -Rf app/cache/*`

I suggest to declare your entity variables as protected (not sure but I mean I've heard of problems using public).

Then you can run `php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AcmeDemoBundle` for creating getter/setter.

Comment: yeah, I've done everything and i think doctrine:generate is the problem. But i don't understand why the attribute must be copied as private from abstract to the extending entity. i will try it now as you said twice.

Comment: ok, i never ran generate:entities allone, now i have the reason. but i don't understand why doctrine is doing this?

Comment: so, i see no other solution to copy the attributes from the mappedsuperclass to the extending entities and removing the abstract entity. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem. But you don't have to define an abstract class for an entity. You could also only define your Class Book which should be enough.

Comment: nono, i have two entities which have mostly the same attributes, but i want to have two different database tables. So i thought the best solution is to create a abstract entity to use it for two entities. the attributes inside the abstract entity were copied to the extending entity when i call php app/console generate:entites  and i don't understand why. i can remove them and after this everything is fine. but this can'T be a solution.